# How do I create a user with no email address in Desire2Learn's Valence APIs?

Tags: desire2learn

If I want to create a new user through Desire2Learn's Valence API, but the user will not have an external email address, how must I provide the new user data?

Answer (score 2):

When you create a new user, you must use the [User.CreateUserData](http://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/res/user.html#User.CreateUserData) structure, and if you want the user to have no external email address, you have to provide a null value for the property:

```
{"UserName": "Test.User",
 "FirstName": "Test", 
 "MiddleName": "", 
 "LastName": "User", 
 "RoleId": "103", 
 "OrgDefinedId": "ext-test-user", 
 "IsActive": true, 
 "ExternalEmail": null,
 "SendCreationEmail": false}
```